# Generic type conversion

Tags: .net, generics

I'm having some serious design problems due to generics issues. Perhaps someone has some suggestions.

EDIT: So, I know this is not usually done, but I've completely changed my example code, because I've realized that the original pseudo-code did not really explain my problem. The following code much more closely resembles the real example I am dealing with. I hope that my problem will be clearer from it. I apologize ahead that it is a bit lengthy, but from my experience, problems with generics usually show up when you try to build a more complex structure. So:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConnector<IService> connector = ConnectorBuilderFactory.NewBuilder<IService>("someEndpoint").MakeReliable().GetConnector();
            connector.Connect();
        }
    }

    public interface IService : IConnectionMaintainable
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public interface IConnectionMaintainable
    {
        DateTime GetServerTime();
    }

    public interface IConnector<T>
    {
        T Channel { get; }
        void Connect();
        void Disconnect();
    }

    public interface IConnectorBuilder<T>
    {
        IConnector<T> GetConnector();
        IConnectorBuilder<T> MakeReliable();
        // ...more connector-configuration methods
    }

    public class ChannelWatchDog<T> where T : IConnectionMaintainable
    {
        private IConnector<T> connector;

        public ChannelWatchDog(IConnector<T> connector /*various other parameters*/)
        {
            this.connector = connector;
        }

        // ...methods that use connector's Connect, Disconnect, and GetServerTime methods
    }

    public class Connector<T> : IConnector<T>
    {
        private T channel;

        public Connector(string endpoint)
        {
            // ...build channel
        }

        public T Channel
        {
            get { return channel; }
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            // ...connect to server
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            // ...disconnect from server
        }
    }

    public class ConnectorBuilder<T> : IConnectorBuilder<T>
    {
        private string endpoint;

        public ConnectorBuilder(string endpoint)
        {
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
        }

        public IConnector<T> GetConnector()
        {
            Connector<T> connector = new Connector<T>(endpoint);

            // If reliability was requested, build the ChannelWatchDog: Following line does not compile:
            // ChannelWatchDog<T> watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog<T>(connector);

            return connector;
        }

        public IConnectorBuilder<T> MakeReliable()
        {
            // save various parameters required to build the ChannelWatchDog
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class ConnectorBuilderFactory
    {
        public static IConnectorBuilder<T> NewBuilder<T>(string endpoint)
        {
            return new ConnectorBuilder<T>(endpoint);
        }
    }
```

So, firstly, if you find the GetConnector method in the ConnectorBuilder class, you will see the commented line of code, which does not compile if uncommented. This line is the essence of my problem. The problem might be obvious from the code, but I will try to explain it anyway in case it is not:

1. I have an internal class (ChannelWatchDog) that needs an IConnector. But not just any IConnector, an IConnector, because other than the non-generic IConnector methods, it also needs the GetServerTime method from the IConnectionMaintainable interface.
2. To simplify construction of connectors, I hoped to implement a builder using the Expression Builder pattern (the IConnectionBuilder interface). However, I want to be able to construct any IConnector, not just IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable>. Therefore, I cannot constrain T in IConnectorBuilder in the same way as I constrain it for the ChannelWatchDog. Lacking this constraint, I have no way to build it when GetConnector is called. Adding the constraint to the MakeReliable method does not help.

So, essentially the reason I posted this question was that I wanted to do something that is apparently impossible. I wanted the ChannelWatchDog and ConnectorBuilder class to look something like this:

```
public class ChannelWatchDog
    {
        private IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable> connector;

        public ChannelWatchDog(IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable> connector /*various other parameters*/)
        {
            this.connector = connector;
        }

        // ...methods that use connector's Connect, Disconnect, and GetServerTime methods
    }

    public class ConnectorBuilder<T> : IConnectorBuilder<T>
    {
        private string endpoint;

        public ConnectorBuilder(string endpoint)
        {
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
        }

        public IConnector<T> GetConnector()
        {
            Connector<T> connector = new Connector<T>(endpoint);

            // If reliability was requested, build the ChannelWatchDog: Following line does not compile:
            ChannelWatchDog watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog((IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable>)connector);

            return connector;
        }

        public IConnectorBuilder<TReliable> MakeReliable<TReliable>() where TReliable : T, IConnectionMaintainable
        {
            // save various parameters required to build the ChannelWatchDog
            return (IConnectorBuilder<TReliable>)this;
        }
    }
```

But the cast to IConnector fails at runtime.

So that was much more lengthy than I had originally intended. If you've gotten this far in reading then you already have my thanks :) 
Any ideas are welcome, including restructuring the code.

BTW, Having not found a solution to this myself, I created different ConnectorBuilders (in this case, a ReliableConnectorBuilder) and different factory methods in the factory. But I don't like this solution much.

EDIT: Just to clarify and reiterate: I cannot constrain the IConnector nor the ConnectionBuilder because these need to support cases in which the IConnectionMaintainable interface is not implemented.

Comment: what's the compilation error on the line that doesn't compile and ... which line is it that fails to cast at runtime? you have 2 different questions (effectively 2 different issues) posted here. which is which? Also can you try to wrap up the question with an actual question rather than just statements?

Comment: @Maslow, the commented line does not compile because the connector is not constrained as required by the ChannelWatchDog. My hoped for solution for this, which is casting connector&lt;T&gt; to connector&lt;IConnectionMaintainable&gt; is what fails at runtime. That is, the line which in the first example does not compile, is the same line which in the second example, after the modification, throws an exception at runtime. And no, it is not 2 separate questions. It is one question where I am providing one of my attempted solutions which failed at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Code to the interface?

```
GenericClass<IFoo> wrapper = new GenericClass<IFoo>(new FooImplementor());
Acceptor acceptor = new Acceptor(wrapper);
```

Comment: Yes that is the obvious solution. It's just that I didn't explain myself all that well :) As soon as I am free I will update my question, as it's a bit more convoluted than it sounds.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've rewritten the question. I know it's quite lengthy but would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

What you want for your GenericClass is called [Covarianz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). Watch [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/bruceky/whirlwind-13-whats-new-in-c-4-covariance--contravariance) for more details. I whould go for Marc's answer, but if this is not what you want, then try this:

```
class GenericClass<out T> { ... }
```

Comment: Very interesting. But I'm working in .net 3.5 and have no option to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using reflection to allow casting the `Connector<T>` to `Connector<IConnectionMaintainable>`, I'm not sure how performance intensive this would be though and it requires being able to clone the `Connector<T>` class.

```
public class Connector<T> : IConnector<T>
{
    // ...
    private Connector()
    {
    }
    // ...
    public static explicit operator Connector<IConnectionMaintainable>(Connector<T> other)
    {
        Connector<IConnectionMaintainable> connector = null;

        Type p = typeof(T);
        if (p.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IConnectionMaintainable)))
        {
            connector = new Connector<IConnectionMaintainable>();
            connector.channel = other.channel as IConnectionMaintainable;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }

        return connector;
    }
}

public class ConnectorBuilder<T> : IConnectorBuilder<T>
{
    // ...
    public IConnector<T> GetConnector()
    {
        Connector<T> connector = new Connector<T>(endpoint);

        // If reliability was requested, build the ChannelWatchDog:
        try 
        {
            Connector<IConnectionMaintainable> temp = (Connector<IConnectionMaintainable>)connector;
            ChannelWatchDog<IConnectionMaintainable> watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog<IConnectionMaintainable>(temp);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Trying to make reliable when not possible");
        }

        return connector;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could have `GenericClass<T>` implement/extend a non-generic interface/base class, much like is the case with lists and enumerables in .NET. The actual generic type could be an abstract method/property returning a Type object, and implemented in the generic class.

Answer (score 0):

If this line not compiling is the main problem:

```
// If reliability was requested, build the ChannelWatchDog: Following line does not compile:
        ChannelWatchDog watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog((IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable>)connector);
```

then I think it should be

```
ChannelWatchDog watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog(connector);
```

except that your runtime cast fails, I believe because the IConnector would need to be constrained:

```
public interface IConnector<T> where T:IConnectionMaintainable
{
    T Channel { get; }
    void Connect();
    void Disconnect();
}
```

This is from the hip, and hopefully provides insight or hints. The constraint does compile as per linqpad.

Also it results in cascading constraint requirements so here's the rest of the code that does compile:

```
void Main()
{

}

// Define other methods and classes here
  public interface IConnectionMaintainable
{
    DateTime GetServerTime();
}

public interface IConnector<T> where T:IConnectionMaintainable
{
    T Channel { get; }
    void Connect();
    void Disconnect();
}

 public interface IConnectorBuilder<T> where T:IConnectionMaintainable
{
    IConnector<T> GetConnector();
    IConnectorBuilder<T> MakeReliable();
    // ...more connector-configuration methods
}
public class ChannelWatchDog
{
    private IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable> connector;

    public ChannelWatchDog(IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable> connector /*various other parameters*/)
    {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    // ...methods that use connector's Connect, Disconnect, and GetServerTime methods
}

public class ConnectorBuilder<T> : IConnectorBuilder<T> where T:IConnectionMaintainable
{
    private string endpoint;

    public ConnectorBuilder(string endpoint)
    {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }
    public IConnectorBuilder<T> MakeReliable()
    {
        // save various parameters required to build the ChannelWatchDog
        return this;
    }
    public IConnector<T> GetConnector()
    {
        Connector<T> connector = new Connector<T>(endpoint);

        // If reliability was requested, build the ChannelWatchDog: Following line does not compile:
        ChannelWatchDog watchDog = new ChannelWatchDog((IConnector<IConnectionMaintainable>)connector);

        return connector;
    }

    public IConnectorBuilder<TReliable> MakeReliable<TReliable>() where TReliable : T, IConnectionMaintainable
    {
        // save various parameters required to build the ChannelWatchDog
        return (IConnectorBuilder<TReliable>)this;
    }
}

 public class Connector<T> : IConnector<T> where T:IConnectionMaintainable
{
    private T channel;

    public Connector(string endpoint)
    {
        // ...build channel
    }

    public T Channel
    {
        get { return channel; }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        // ...connect to server
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        // ...disconnect from server
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can see in the original post that what I ended up doing was similar to this: I created an additional ConnectionBuilder where T is constrained. But my intention with this question was to see if there was a different, hopefully more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the generic parameter T in the class ConnectorBuilder implement the interface IConnectionMaintainable. The reason for this is that it is needed for the generic type of ChannelWatchDog. The generic T is not strict enough for the generic type parameter of ChannelWatchDog.